# How to integrate IBM Watson assistant with IBM Discovery

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I was successfully able to integrate Watson Discovery with IBM Watson virtual assistant. I have a scenario, where the discovery collection is a combination of multiple collections of user-trained models. one collection contains document passages as responses and the other contain question and answer-based structure. If I want to integrate my discovery to Watson, I have created the search skill with passage text as response body. how can I get the answer response from my other collection to my Watson virtual assistant response.